# Android is not deeplinking to google play

Tags: android, google-play, deep-linking

I have made a special URL to which, if browsed to, if it has Android in the user-agent, it redirects (302) to google play to download the app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={app_name}

Thing is, it doesn't deeplink. it will open the google play in that app, but inside the browser.
How can that be achieved? I dont want to have a button on the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `https://`, you can use `market://` for Play store links. Google describes it here: http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html

The link would look like `market://details?id=<package_name>`.

Comment: actually they are saying to use the http for web site and market within the android

Comment: If you're trying to open the link in the Google Play app, you should use the market:// link. I believe you can use JavaScript to open the link how you want.

`window.location.href= "market://details?id=<packagename>";`